# Function wont find element from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, properties, null, innerhtml

im doing a project on school, where we are making a website, and modularity was very important. therefore i put the header in innerHTML since it was going to be used on every page. i have a counter which use an element in that innerHTML, but when i call the counter it just says "Cannot set property of innerHTML of null. I've searched for hours but it dont seem to be any other who have had this exact problem.

The counter worked perfectly until i put the html in innerHTML..
I've laso tried to put the script both just under the header which the innerHTML is for, AND at the bottom, and under the body end-tag. all with the same result.

Here's the code for html and javascript. i've only taken with the lines that is used for this.

```js
loadTop();
function loadTop() {
   document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = 
   '<div class="topbar">'+
       '<div class="cart">'+
           '<output type="number" id="orderCount">0</output>'
       '</div>'+
   '</div>';

  
}
       
window.onload = loadTop;
       
const cartNow = document.getElementById("orderCount");
let cartNum = 0;
 function cartCounter() {
    cartNum += 1;
    cartNow.innerHTML = cartNum;
    cartNow.style.opacity = 1;
    console.log(cartNow);
 }
```

```html
<body>
        <header id="header"></header>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <button id="oatmeal" onclick="cartCounter()"> + </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call the JavaScript function at the beginning of your .js file, like this:

```
loadTop();

function loadTop() {
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML =
        '<div class="topbar">' +
        '<div id="overskrift"><a href="index.html">ELEMENT</a></div>' +

        '<!--STJERNE-->' +
        '<div class="cart">' +
        '<output type="number" id="orderCount">0</output>'
}

const cartNow = document.getElementById("orderCount");
let cartNum = 0;
function cartCounter() {
    cartNum += 1;
    cartNow.innerHTML = cartNum;
    cartNow.style.opacity = 1;
    console.log(cartNow);
}
```

[image]

Comment: oh my god it worked! Thank you so much! The counter works.
if you dont mind, here is another question: when i did this, i got another error inside the loadTop function, on a line with an ordinary innerHTML for the footer. and its the same error message..now the text in the footer is gone because the innerHTML ther is null.

Comment: **You could edit this question** and update it with the complete code to be able to solve the errors that it shows you.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure `loadTop()` has been called before assigning cartNow. Else cartNow will be null.

```js
const cartNow = document.getElementById("orderCount")
```

EDIT :
I think you should not use onload for loading your page as onload has be thought to be call after the page is "loaded". Instead I recommand you to call your loadTop before closing your body. Then use onload event to register your events. I am not a frontend optimisation expert so maybe there are more elegant/performant solutions but it should be enought for you school project anyway.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const cartNow = document.getElementById("orderCount");
    let cartNum = 0;
    document.getElementById('oatmeal').addEventListener('click',  function cartCounter() {
        cartNum += 1;
        cartNow.innerHTML = cartNum;
        cartNow.style.opacity = 1;
        console.log(cartNow);
     });
});
```

```html
<body>
    <header id="header"></header>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <button id="oatmeal"> + </button>
    <script>
        (function() {
           document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = 
           '<div class="topbar">'+
               '<div class="cart">'+
                   '<output type="number" id="orderCount">0</output>'
               '</div>'+
           '</div>'
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: So what i didn't include her is that loadTop i called by window.onload = loadTop;. loadTop is in its own script-file, and cartCounter in another, this is because someone in my group decided. but the same error occured when they were in the same script-file also.. 
I make sure that the script with loadTop is called before the script with cartCounter and cartNow..

Comment: Well, cartNow will be called before window.onload event.

Comment: oh i see, im sorry i misunderstood! i got it to work now! but now there is new errors..

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked out now. thank you both so much. I thought i had to use window.onload for some reason i got somewehere on the web, but i removed that, and put just loadTop() at the top, and it was all fixed! finally, Good night!